# problem with multiple user dependent on each other in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working with some custom-made user models in **Django**. They are the following:

1. `myCustomeUser` responsible for the primary identity of a user
2. `Industry` is a user that will link with `OneToOneField` to the `myCustomeUser`
3. `Employee` is another user account, which will FK to the `myCustomeUser` and FK to `Industry`

my `models.py`:

```
class myCustomeUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique="True", blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    is_Employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Industry = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Industry(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='industry_releted_user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    license = models.IntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
    industry_extrafield = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Now I need to write the model of `Employee`. There are some conditions also:

- It should contain `name`, `National ID`, `gmail`, `rank`, `employee_varified`, named fields
- This will inherit the `myCustomeUser` and `Industry` both
- The `Industry` account user will primarily entry all the data of `Employee` in the database, except `username` and `password`(which are inherited from `myCustomeUser`)
- Later on, the `Employee` will search his `National ID` given by the `Industry` and finish the registration process by creating his `username` and `password`.

I have tried the `Employee` model like this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(myCustomeUser,primary_key=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    National_ID = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    gmail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
    employee_varified = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
```

But the problem with this model is I cannot create any `Employee` object without giving `user` (that means `username` and `password`), But the `Industry` user needs to entry their `Employee`'s data, before complete the `Employee`'s registration.

how can I write my `Employee` model to solve this problem?

Comment: If you want to create an object without setting up the related object, set `blank=True` in the kwargs for the field. Also, don't set the `id` field on the custom user, Django will do that for you. Also don't make the `user` the primary key for the Employee. Keep the primary key as the default `id` field.

Comment: thanks for the help, now it is working perfectly!

Comment: Excellent. Will post a proper answer in that case 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't guarantee that a related object will exist when you create an object, you can make the relationship(s) optional.

So in your case, I'd create your model more like;

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        myCustomeUser,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    industry = models.ForeignKey(
        Industry,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    national_id = models.IntegerField(
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        unique=True
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        blank=False,
        null=True
    )
    # ... etc
```

You may also benefit from having a look through the following site which might help you learn a thing or two about django

https://www.django-antipatterns.com/